# Daily check in and out, that automatically deletes the rows from google sheet and form responses

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

We are trying to create a check-in and check-out system that people has to scan in at when they arrive and scan out at when they leave. I got the sheet set up and linked to the form. I can get the sheet to register all the scans, but I cant get the sheet to delete all rows on its own. Basically the way it works is someone comes in scans in, the sheet pops up there name and a timestamp. When they leave they scan again and it pops up the persons name and another time stamp. I would like it to be able to automatically delete all rows in the sheet and all the responses from the form. If it is only able to delete the sheet rows that will be fine as well

I tried coping a couple of the other codes I found on here like this: (Spacing my be a little off)

```
function myFunction() {
  function DeleteOldEntries() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
//give your sheet name below instead of Sheet1
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses");

var datarange = sheet.getDataRange();
var lastrow = datarange.getLastRow();


var currentDate = new Date();
var oneDayago = new Date();
oneDayago.setDate(currentDate.getDate() - 1);

for (i=lastrow;i>=2;i--) {
  var tempdate = sheet.getRange(i, 2).getValue();

  if(tempdate < oneDayago)
  {
    sheet.deleteRow(i);
  }
 }
var form, urlForm = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getFormUrl('https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1AFfUhcfPgCGJocFfjsFcOJvnRN1O_LCJkcJlwm2GeLw/edit');
if (urlForm) {
form = FormApp.openByUrl(urlForm);
if (form) form.deleteAllResponses();
}
  }
}
```

So far I got it to run okay in App Scripts but past that I've gotten stuck. I don't know how to get it to run it on sheets or the form. So any help on this would be apricated. I have less than basic script training.

Comment: If I understood you correctly your only problem is how to have it run repeatedly? If that's the case then all you need to do is setup a trigger to run on repeat. Since you delete anything that is before the previous day running it more often than daily makes little sense. The way the script is worded it has to run on the spreadsheet where the responses are placed, so keep it there, setup a timed trigger and have it run daily.

Comment: Why do you want to delete rows?

Comment: @Cooper - So we are using the check in as a way to verify people in and out of the building. For like in case there is a fire and we all need to evacuate. We wanted to have a digital log of everyone that came in for the day, and be able to know that everyone got out. We have a Hybrid working schedule and, aside from my department, the other departments aren't aways there and/or don't keep a regular schedule with coming into the office

Comment: @Vytautas - Okay so you are saying not to worry about clearing the form, but just clearing the form responses in the google sheet, correct? If so how do i get it to run in the sheet? I had been going to Extensions -> App Scripts - > Creating new code by pasting the code above -> set trigger to run every day between midnight and 1 am, but so far it hasn't deleted the responses. I tried to do it every minute as a test and still nothing, so what else do I need to do? This is my first time trying to use a script to do anything.

Comment: No, I meant that the way your code is worded is that it's coded for a spreadsheet (as you said yourself you went Extensions → App Scripts and added the new code, the other option is having a standalone script you can point to anything, but then `.getActiveSpreadSheet()` does not work, that's what I mean by the way it's worded. You can keep the clearing of the form, just that all you need to do is setup a trigger in the same menu where you write the code to run on repeat if you just want to clear it after the day is over

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function DeleteOldEntries() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses");
  let vs = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow(), sh.getLastColumn()).getValues()
  var lastrow = datarange.getLastRow();
  var dt = new Date();
  var ydtv = new Date(dt.getFullYear(), dt.getMonth(), dt.getDate() - 1).valueOf();
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    tdv = new Date(r[1]).valueOf();
    if (tdt < ydtv) {
      sh.deleteRow(i);
    }
  })
  const urlForm = ss.getFormUrl();
  if (urlForm) {
    const form = FormApp.openByUrl(urlForm);
    if (form) form.deleteAllResponses();
  }
}
```

Comment: I copied and pasted the code in to the App Script and got this error:                                            7:38:22 AM Error ReferenceError: datarange is not defined
                                             DeleteOldEntries @ Code.gs:5

Comment: Well that's because `datarange` is not defined.  I just copied it from your code and modified the data manipulation for you. I can run it because I don't have any data so it's not reproducible perhaps you read about [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

```
  function DeleteResponses() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1Cn9RwhyPG3l-QWmhlRE-eUt8-HUcENXj7hA2VAmcFGE");
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses");

    var datarange = sheet.getDataRange();
    var lastrow = datarange.getLastRow();

   var currentDate = new Date();
   currentDate.setDate(new Date().getDate() + 1)
    var onedayago = new Date();
    onedayago.setDate(currentDate.getDate() - 1);

    for (i=lastrow;i>=2;i--) {
      var tempdate = sheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue();

       if(tempdate < onedayago)
      {
        sheet.deleteRow(i);
  };
  }
  }
```

This was the code I ended up getting to work. I don't know why adding in the line for current date is setdate + 1 but it worked

Comment: i tried to make an edit but edit queue was currently full